# Getting an extra line when using persistant data and keymaps. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I'm new to keymaps and persistent storage. For some reason I'm getting an extra line when using a for loop to get a map variable. Everything seems to work right until I have it update the textview and it adds an extra string.

I will post a snippet of my code bellow
I will also post the screenshot of the textview after I push the button.

```
static SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Context context = this;

        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putString("test 01/16/1990 - 12:30AM", "211");
        editor.putString("test 05/26/2017 - 9:50AM", "166");
        editor.commit();


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testTextView);

 chart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chartBtn);
        chart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                tv.setText("Testing : \n");
                Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();

                for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
                    tv.append("\n Dat-Time : " + entry.getKey() + " / Sugars: " + entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EqAg.png)

Comment: Sure looks like `prefs` already had something in it before you started adding your stuff in.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem. I'm not sure how to set this as answered lol